# Export date with specified format

Tags: export, date-and-time

My problem is that I want use *PGFplot* in $\LaTeX$ to draw my graphs, which x axis is a date. Therefore the output file has to have one column *"UTC time" (YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss)* and the second one is the corresponding data list.

Would it be possible to specify the date format of `Export[]` ?

Comment: Use `DateString` to get the right formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the solution would be (thanks to Pickett)

```
DateString[#, {"Year", "-", "Month", "-", "Day", " ", "Hour", ":", "Minute", ":", "Second"}]&/@dates
```

Once the transformation done, export the thing !